# How to append data to a column in a loop

Tags: excel, vba

My script takes data from multiple sheets and creates a new spreadsheet. The problem I am running into is how to append to the end of a column. I tried this:

```
LastRow = Sheets("Test").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Where LastRow is defined as a long but I ran into an error when my loop continued going around. Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub autoFill()
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Unit As String
    Dim ddg As Variant, i As Variant

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Mapping")
    ddg = ws.Range("F4:F21").Value
    For Each i In ddg
        Unit = "Unit #" & i
        LastRow = Sheets("Test").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets(Unit).Range("A2:A100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("A1" & LastRow)
        Sheets(Unit).Range("B2:B100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("B1" & LastRow)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pick a range WAY above whatever the last row might be in whatever column will be populated (A in this case) when using `xlUp`. Add 1 to get to the next row:

```
LastRow = Sheets("Test").Range("A50000").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

LAstRow now has a number that is equal to the first unused row in Column A of sheet Test.

Now concatenate that number to "A" to make a range like "A50". Right now you are doing:

```
Sheets(Unit).Range("A2:A100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("A1" & LastRow)
```

Which is concatenating the number to "A1" so you get "A150" which is nonsense... Instead:

```
Sheets(Unit).Range("A2:A100").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Test").Range("A" & LastRow)
```